# OnCreate instead of OnResume/OnRestart?

Tags: android, oncreate, onresume, application-restart

I have some Activities, let's say Activity A, B and C.
In the Activity A I call the B through a Menu with an `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
Intent main = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
this.startActivity(main);
```

Now, when I'm in the B activity, I can call the A one back in the same way (with Intent and startactivity): how can i handle it to call the `OnResume` or the `OnRestart` method of A instead of the `OnCreate` one?

I'm logging it and anytime I move from an activity to another one, it always call the `OnCreate` method: what can I do?

Comment: Are you done with Activity B and want to go back to A?  Or do you want to keep B around for some reason?  If its the first, just call finish() and end B.

Comment: I suggest you to study this tutorial and code example http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Configure your Activity A as "singleTask" or "singleInstance" in the manifest.xml.  Then Acitivity A's onResume() will be fire instead of onCreate() when you call Activity A from Activity B (assuming Activity A was already instantiated like you describe).  There are drawbacks to this kind of configuration so read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

example manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityA"     
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"      
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control whether the OnCreate/OnResume/OnRestart methods are called directly. It is based on whether the previous activity is still in memory or not.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html
http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Comment: [You can.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964943/why-do-oncreate-should-be-called-only-once-on-the-start-of-activity/13964977#13964977) I've tested it.

Comment: Just because you can does not mean that you should.  Calling onCreate() manually is a massive code smell to me and indicates bad design and misuse of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm logging it and anytime I move from an activity to another one, it always call the OnCreate method: what can I do?

To return to Activity A from Activity B, if you use:

- `startActivity()`, then A's `onCreate()` will always be called.
- `finish()`, then A's `onCreate()` may or may not be called. (It depends on whether A was destroyed by you or the OS.)